# How do I make a collision in pygame with 2 images?

Tags: python, pygame

So I am trying to make a collision with 2 images, I even used get_rect but still doesnt work for me. In function draw i tried to make the collision with player_rect and rect_img which is an image of GRASS_IMAGE, any help is appreciated.

If you want to test the code, create 2 python file one main.py and second mapdata.py, in the main include the first code i wrote and in the mapdata include the second one. And change the .png (images).

Sorry if the code is hard to read or is written bad.

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
import os
from pygame import image
from pygame import rect
from mapdata import game_map_data

#CONSTANT VARIABLES
#WIDTH;HEIGHT
WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 598
PLAYER_WIDTH = 20
PLAYER_HEIGHT = 20
#COLORS
COLOR_DARKBLUE = 'darkblue'
COLOR_RED = 'red'
#WINDOW
WINDOW = pg.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT))
sky = pg.image.load('sky.png')
sky = pg.transform.scale(sky,(800,599))

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def Draw(self):
        self.player = pg.image.load('player.png')
        self.player = pg.transform.scale(self.player,(PLAYER_WIDTH,PLAYER_HEIGHT))
        self.player_rect = self.player.get_rect()
        WINDOW.blit(self.player,dest=(self.x,self.y))
        self.player_rect.x = self.x
        self.player_rect.y = self.y

        if self.rect_img.colliderect(self.player_rect): #COLLISIONS DONT WORK
            print("collided")

    def handle_keys(self,speed):
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        self.speed = speed
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += speed
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= speed
        if keys[pg.K_DOWN]:
            self.y+= speed
        if keys[pg.K_UP]:
            self.y -= speed

    ###########
    ##TILEMAP##
    ###########

    def tile(self,data,tile_size,img_size):
        self.tile_list = []

        #TEXTURES
        GRASS_IMAGE = pg.image.load('platform.jpg')
        #stone_img = pg.image.load('')

        row_count = 0
        self.tile_size = tile_size
        self.img_size = img_size

        for row in data:
            col_count = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1:
                    img = pg.transform.scale(GRASS_IMAGE,(img_size,img_size))
                    self.rect_img = img.get_rect()
                    self.rect_img.x = col_count * tile_size
                    self.rect_img.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img,self.rect_img)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                col_count += 1
            row_count += 1


    def draw_tile(self):
        for tile in self.tile_list:
            WINDOW.blit(tile[0], tile[1])


#FPS
clock = pg.time.Clock()




game_map_data = game_map_data


#PLAYER
player = Player(x=30,y=30,width=PLAYER_WIDTH,height=PLAYER_HEIGHT)
gamemap = player.tile(game_map_data,17,20)
while True:
    FPS = 60
    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

    
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    SKY_POSITION = (0,0)

    WINDOW.blit(sky,SKY_POSITION)
    player.draw_tile()
    #player.col()
    player.Draw()
    player.handle_keys(speed=3)
    pg.display.update()
    pg.display.flip()
```

tilemap (mapdata.py): ACTUAL MAP

```
game_map_data = [
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.rect_img` is the rect of the last grass tile that you set by going through the for loops in `tile` function. So,

`self.rect_img.colliderect(self.player_rect):`

is actually only testing the last grass tile.

You need to test against all the tiles, not just the last one. Luckily, you are storing those tiles in a list, so you can go through that list can check against player and all the tiles.

```
 for t in self.tile_list:
      if t[1].colliderect(self.player_rect): #COLLISIONS DONT WORK
            print("collided")
```

Also, you code could be faster if you load and transform your images once instead of every frame.

Answer (score 0):

To make two objects collide you can use colliderect:
Rect = rectangle

```
if Rect1.colliderect(Rect2):
```

Then by using this you can determine what you want Rect1 to do when it collides with Rect2. In this case we want the player to stop or be blocked.

```
 if Rect1.colliderect(Rect2):
   Rect1.bottom = Rect2.top #changing y pos
   Rect1.left = Rect2.right #changing x pos
   Rect1.right = Rect.left #changing x pos
   Rect1.top = Rect.bottom #changing y pos
```

This will stop Rect1 from moving when it hits Rect2.
I don't know if that helps but i hope it can give you an idea of the possibilities for this collision.